# packer - hyperv - centos dracut initqueue timeout errors

Tags: centos, dracut, hyper-v, packer

facing errors while using packer to build an image with hyperv for centos8

attaching logs at ends

1. its picking the ks.cfg,
2. its getting the ip as well from dhcp, i could see in the rdsosreport.txt as well
3. but still the dracut initqueue remains the same error could not boot the centos8 to build image using packer on hyperv

[image: Linux dracut initqueue errors]